# How to Get shape Name (Groupshapes name)

Tags: excel, vba

> **What code does:** I have the following code: That is, I can get the "ParentGroup.Name" by clicking on the shape of the group shape.
>
> **Problem:** For two or more group shapes, each other group shape has the same some child shapes
>
> ***Example:*** Gruop_1 has four child shapes, and the child shape names are Shape_1, Shape_2, shape_3, and Shape_4.
>
> Gruop_2 also has the same four child shapes. The child shapes are also named Shape_1, Shape_2, shape_3, Shape_4.
>
> When I click **Gruop_1**, the **MsgBox result** will be **Group_1**, but When I click **Group_2**, the result will also be Gruop_1.
>
> **What I want to do:** How do I get **Gruop_2** when I click **Gruop_2**?

```
Sub GetshapeName()
    On Error GoTo line1
    Dim shp As shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ParentGroup
line1:
    If shp Is Nothing Then
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    End If
    MsgBox shp.Name
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem right, are you sure your second group is named correctly?

Comment: I just did a test and your code worked for me.

Comment: If two group shapes have different children shapes, the macro gives the expected result that I want, but if completely identical, the result is the name of the source shape.
In the example above. 
I copied the group shape and only changed the name for the group, the names of the children in that group remained the same.

Comment: Is that may be why macros don't work as expected?

Comment: One more Question:
I'm using a copy of the shape by holding down the Ctrl key and dragging the left mouse button. Is there any change in the two shapes ❓(Example: shape.ID, shape.Name, etc)

Comment: Let me get this straight. You have two groups.Each group consists of 1 oval and 4 rectangles. Is that correct? Or is the oval an individual shape and the 4 rectangles are grouped? If I understand correctly, you want to be able to click on each group and get the group's name. Is that correct?

Comment: There are two groups. Each group consists of only four rectangles. And that's exactly what I wanted! I want to click each group and get the name of the group.

Comment: I also posted my question on this website with a sample file. Please refer to it.

Comment: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1319565-how-to-get-groupshape-name-in-case-2-or-more-group-have-identical-children-shapes.html